# Replace elements from a component of a list

Tags: r

I have an object of class alignment (secuen) after reading an alignment with read.alignment (library seqinr). It has four components, the one I am interested is "nam" which stores the names of secuences. I also have a data.frame (samples) with two variables, one with the names of secuences (it has more names of sequences than the first object) and the name of the sample to each sequence belongs to. I would like to replace the names of sequence by the name of the sample whenever names of sequences mathc between the two objects. I have tried with grep, and some for loops, but I could not get it. 
Example

```
> sequen$nam #(length 3091)
"HZSC42M02F3H7C" "HZSC42M02F2MMT" "HZSC42M02F03D5"
> samples
 V1              V2   
HZSC42M02F3H7C sample_1
HZSC42M02F2MMT sample_2
HZSC42M02F03D5 sample_3
```

`sequen$nam` (length 3091) is a vector (`is.vector` returns `TRUE`) and an character (`is.character` returns `TRUE`), but `sample$V1` (length 61632) is not a vector nor a character

How can I proceed? I am working with R

Comment: At a guess, `samples` is a data frame and `samples$V1` is a factor.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution,

with macth to find columns where sequence names coincide in the two files

```
test<-match(sequen$nam,samples$V1)
```

then removing non coinciding columns from one file and conserving only the new names

```
pre<-sample[test,] 
pre1<-pre[,2]
```

finally writing a new fasta file with the new sequence names (pre1) and sequences from the sequen list.

```
write.fasta(sequences = sec$seq, names = pre1, nbchar = 478, file.out = "final_test.fasta")
```